# Clicking on Unity Build and release Does nothing! Weird

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

So I was following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=khavGQ7Dy3c until 8.28 and until then everything was ok. I checked the project working on my mac camera. However after setting my bundle identifier (i have apple dev id and all certificates are loaded in my keychain so no worries), i click Build and Run, it asks to provide me location, I make a folder and then nothing happens. The folder is made, but no xcode project inside. I tried 2/3 times but same.

Comment: Check console in Unity. There must be some errors which are preventing the build.

Comment: i also just saw a comment "Unable to access Unity Services". please request membership to this project...this is a message i got on the build settings panel on top side.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the message to question?

Comment: And btw you can follow [this](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/09/10/unity-services-are-just-a-few-clicks-away/)

Answer (score 0):

sorry guys...i got the answer. i was signed inside with a student limited access acount...also i did not provide camera description neede to open the ios camera. I made a new account in unity, signed in via studio, and puff..all error were fixed.